# Slice a JSON string

Tags: javascript, parsing, json, slice

I have fetched data from MySQL and echoed JSON encoded data as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM order_list");
$myjsons = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $myjsons[$i] = json_encode(array($row));
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($myjsons);
```

And I have a Javascript function that reads the string and shows it in a text box:

```
if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
$.post('userfind.php', function(data) {
    $("#txtfld").val(data);
    var arr =data.slice(1);
    var user_arr = arr.slice(0,-1);
    var json = user_arr,
    obj = JSON.parse(json);
    alert(obj.user_id);
    $("#resultTXT").val(obj.user_id);
    },'json'
    );}
}
ajaxRequest.open("POST", "userfind.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
    }
```

The problem is that txtfld shows the string as [{"user_id":"2790","fre.....tst":""}] and resultTXT shows nothing because of the two [ ]. I have tried to remove them using slice but it seems that the slice doesn't work on JSON strings. What else can I do to remove [ ] so that the resultTXT shows the user_id?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you convert the array 2 times to json.
2. php doesn't need the a index for the next array element
3. i would also add the correct header "application/json"
4. $row is already a associative array

---

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM order_list");
$myjsons = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $myjsons[] = $row;
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($myjsons);
```

this gives you a proper formatted json

to access your json in javascript u do:

```
var obj=JSON.parse(json);
```

i assume that your mysql returns a list of orders or users [{"user_id":1},{"user_id":2}] so if you want to access the first user's id:

```
obj[0].user_id
```

but if i misunderstand u could post more info about your json.